# what's are the differences between the following ways of executing a method?

Tags: python, oop

so I stumbled upon two ways of executing a method of class on object:

```
class A:
   def good(self):
        print("good")

class B:
   def goodi(self):
      print("good")


a = A()
a.good() #way1
A.good(a) #way2
```

so it all works fine, though when doing for example:

```
B.goodi(a)
```

it will work. but when doing:

```
a.goodi()
```

it will fail.

Comment: class `A` does not have a method called `goodi` so you can't call `a.goodi()` since `a` is of type `A`

Answer (score 0):

This fails because `goodi` isn't a method of `A class`

The previous case works `B.goodi(a)` because the `B class` contains the `gooid method`